# What is the usage of startItem Property in Site Configuration node

Tags: configuration

In the sitecore configuration, we use site configuration nodes to define websites and its properties.

When checked in **site** configuration nodes, there is **startItem** property with values to sitecore content item.

What is the usage of this **startItem** setting?

Answer (score 1):

The path to the start Item of the site. This Item will be opened by default when the site is requested. All relative URL paths will be relative to the startItem.

[See Documentation](https://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties/startItem.aspx)